# Crop a Bitmap and have the same "Size" image afterward

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, bitmap, resolution

I have an image I am taking from a webcam.  I need to offer the illusion of zooming on this image.

Since the webcam does not have optical zoom, I am doing this by cropping the image.

This all works great.

But after I crop the image, I watermark some a date stamp and a branding image on top of the image.

**The Problem:** If I have cropped the image, then the resulting text and branding watermark appear very large. (The branding image covers almost half the horizontal space of the image.)

If I have not cropped the image, then they appear the normal size. (The branding image covers about 1/16 of the horizontal size of the image.)

This is (of course) because the cropped image is smaller, but the branding image remains the same size. 
**Is there a way to crop an image so that the resulting image is the same "size" (as explained above)?**

I would rather not have to dynamically adjust the size of my watermarking.

**What I have tried:**

- [How can I crop image without changing its resolution in C#.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/857147/16241)

  - This uses `bitmap.Clone`
- [How to crop an image using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c)

  - It has several cropping options:

    - `Graphics.FromImage` and `Graphics.DrawImage`
    - `bitmap.SetResolution`

Code:

```
public static Bitmap CropAtRect(Bitmap bitmap, Rectangle rect)
{
   Bitmap croppedBitmap = bitmap.Clone(rect, bitmap.PixelFormat);
   croppedBitmap.SetResolution(bitmap.HorizontalResolution,bitmap.VerticalResolution);
   return croppedBitmap;
}

private Bitmap BrandImage(Bitmap bitmapImage)
{       
   waterMarker = new WaterMarker();
   Bitmap brandedImage = waterMarker.BrandImage(bitmapImage, DateTime.Now.ToString());
   return brandedImage;
}
```

WaterMarker comes from this CodeProject:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2927/Creating-a-Watermarked-Photograph-with-GDI-for-NET

Comment: You want to Crop then Scale then Brand in that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a step.  Add "Scale" into there.

Instead of
Crop -> Brand

Crop -> Scale (resize back to original size) -> Brand

Here is a stack overflow on how scale an image in C#.
[Resize image proportionally with MaxHeight and MaxWidth constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501797/resize-image-proportionally-with-maxheight-and-maxwidth-constraints)

Comment: That was it!  Seems so obvious now.  Thank you!